# WebView loadHTMLString:baseURL: not loading css

Tags: ios, css, webview

I have this this code:

```
NSURL *mainBundleURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlFile baseURL:mainBundleURL];
```

I know the htmlFile is correct. It has inside:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

I also know the stylesheet.css in in the mainBundle. I checked the project.app contents.

Problem is that is the webview is empty. But if I use base Url as nil:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlFile baseURL:nil];
```

The webview shows the content, but without the css file.

I have no idea why this is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW i´m trying in ios 6.1

Comment: Why not load the html from an `NSURLRequest`?

Comment: I only have the html file in a string.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using the resourceURL property

```
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL];
```

and then `[webView loadHTMLString:htmlFile baseURL:baseURL];`

-Sal

Answer (score 1):

Most examples reference `baseUrl: nil` but in order to access the CSS file you need to reference the bundle so that the `<link rel="stylesheet" ...` can access the file.

This is my solution in Swift 3:

```
let baseUrl : URL = Bundle.main.resourceURL! as URL
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "*html file name*", ofType: "html")
let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

Credit the Sal's answer for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhabs `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method blocks your request. Try this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString hasPrefix:@"file"]) {return YES;}

    //deal with the request
}
```